# Google trends no longer showing GEO_CHART_o_o

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization, google-trends

I run a website and after having my tool successfully work for multiple months it's strange to me how it's just stopped working for the particular purpose.

I send Google visualisation requests to the URL:
https://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q=QUERYGOESHERE&cid=GEO_MAP_0_0&export=3&w=500&h=300&date=today%201-m

and now Google Trends seems to respond with:

```
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","status":"error","errors":[{"reason":"other","message":"Could not complete request","detailed_message":"Not enough search volume to show results."}]});
```

This was working for **practically any realistic search term you can think of**. Now it's working for only very popular search terms. Is it possible Google Trends has changed/updated? Is there any reason my request is now outdated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check format of the search keywords

you can provide up to 5 keywords, separated with commas

this will result in error

```
q=QUERYGOESHERE
```

this works...

```
q=QUERY,GOES,HERE
```

test...
[fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q=QUERY,GOES,HERE&cid=GEO_MAP_0_0&export=3&w=500&h=300&date=today%201-m](https://trends.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q=QUERY,GOES,HERE&cid=GEO_MAP_0_0&export=3&w=500&h=300&date=today%201-m)

*again*

error...

```
q=tn%20vols
```

success...

```
q=tn,vols
```

Comment: This doesn't make data appear or start working, this just puts it in an unusable form for the Google charts